# Solution for covering carpet glued to concrete on a balcony

Tags: outdoor, vinyl-flooring

Florida. Early morning sun. Large lanai (2 open sides) has carpet glued to concrete and it is 30 years old and impossible to clean from dust, small grass cutoffs from landscaping  etc.. What can I install over it so I would be able to clean it regularly? It gets wet during storms. I could also cover it partially, only the area near the door and W/D that are on the balcony. I have  a full box of Peel and Stick Vinyl Tile from Home Depot left over. Can I use it? I don't want mold growing underneath the whatever I instal.

Comment: Why not remove the carpet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm dubious that there's a solution that will work on top of the existing carpet; as you suggest, mold **would** be a problem.

Comment: removing carpet is out of the question at this time. Single disabled person. The carpet is an outdoor carpet.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Florida's climate, covering it with anything will end up with mold underneath.  Perhaps you can hire a high-school kid for cheap to help with the labor in removing it.

Comment: If you can't remove it, try a Chernobyl approach. I bet you can seal the carpet (if it's not shaggy) in 2-part epoxy while it's dry, like the kind used for garage floors. Apply with a roller, repeat coats until smooth. Once the carpret is entombed, you can do something on top (ex tile) without worrying about mold.

Comment: Wouldn't it be slippery? The carpet is not shaggy.

Answer (score 4):

It's a pain in the neck but you need to remove and dispose of the carpet. Anything you put on top of it will only cover a nasty mess that will get worse over time.

Once the carpet is removed you will need to clean the cement of carpet glue. There are many videos and guides for how to remove carpet glue.

Once the cement is prepped you have options. The vinyl tile you mention needs to be rated for outdoor use. Sunshine is hard on plastics. You don't want to install something that will be as big a mess as the carpet later on.

Options:
Not a complete list...

- Leave the cement plain. This is the lowest effort/cost solution.
- Stain the cement. There is a trend toward stained cement. You'll need something that is outdoor appropriate. Lots of videos and guides on how to stain cement.
- Outdoor tile - this isn't cheap but it is durable, easy to clean and looks nice.

I like to get an estimate for what it will take to hire work done. This tells me how much money I'm saving if I do it myself - makes me feel good. On the other hand, if the estimate is reasonable I might let them do the work!

Comment: I actually like the "Leave the cement plain" solution. I would be able to keep it clean at least.